# how to avoid to use memcpy to create a string

Tags: c++, c++17

My programmer has lots of memcpy. I want to avoid them.

I want to get a struct like boost::string_ref.
I want to know.

```
uint32_t len = 20;
char *p = new char[len];
memset(p, 0x00, len)
memcpy(p, "aaaa", 4);
string str(p, 4);// whether is use memcpy or not ?
const string str2(p, 4); //whether is use memcpy or not
//if it used memcpy, how to avoid memcpy ?
```

string_ref->string

string_view->string

string->string_ref

string->string_view

char* ->string

string->string

please tell me how to judge whether function used memcpy ?

Comment: Why is it important for you to know if memcpy is used internally in ```string str(p, 4)```?

Comment: Google profiler tell me my programmer has lots of memcpy. I want to avoid them.

Comment: It is the compiler's job to use or avoid `memcpy` when appropriate.  Until you come up with concrete evidence that this is a problem or bottleneck in your program, I think you should find some other issue with which to concern yourself.

Comment: @zhaozheng please link to the "Google prefiler".

Comment: @BlueTune  I'm sorry, I has a wrong word prefiler->profiler.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) to avoid copying the string.

```
#include <string_view>
// ...

const string_view strview(p, 4);
```

Keep in mind that string views are not guaranteed to be null-terminated, so be careful when using them in APIs that expect a null-terminated `char*`. Also, when the string they are viewing goes out of scope, the string view itself becomes invalid (just like a pointer would.)

Comment: Thank you!, other question:My module return std::string to extranal. I want to get a to_string function without memcpy, do you have any idea？

Comment: @zhaozheng Depends on what the returned string is. Is it a class data member? In that case, you can return a `const std::string&`. However, I cannot say for sure without more information.